# Gitlab with Synology Users?

Tags: javascript, docker, gitlab, synology

Today I installed GitLab on my Synology DS 718+ with the official package manager. I found a beautiful login and register page, but I cannot login with the predefined Synology users.

Is there a way to use Synology users also as GitLab users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is an LDAP server that manages all the users. This server can be used for Synology and for GitLab.

See:

- [Synology LDAP](https://kb.synology.com/en-nz/DSM/help/DSM/AdminCenter/file_directory_service_ldap?version=6)
- [GitLab LDAP](https://docs.gitlab.com/12.10/ee/administration/auth/ldap.html)

Answer (score 1):

I am using the Git server. There you define a specific Git user (with  some pain during setup). Should be the same for Gitlab.

Otherwise check the application access rights (unfortunately in Synology there are 2 or 3 different pages where to maintain them).

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I need more advanced features like runner and issue boards, etc.